# Change UI immediately after receiving UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification

Tags: iphone, ios7, uikit, nsnotificationcenter, application-lifecycle

I need to make changes in my UI immediately when I receive UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification. 
 Here is what I do:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(applicationWillResignActive:)
                                             name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(NSNotification *) notification {
//    my changes (hide some views, change bg color, change text, etc)
//    ...
}
```

The problem is that those changes are applied only after the application returns to the active state. So the user can see for a moment the previous state of UI.
Is there any workaround to solve this problem?

Comment: How are you updating your UI? Are you on the main thread?